# How to replace token string with object value

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am building a Rails 5 app. In this app the user can save a "token" into string and then the system will automatically replace the token with a real object value.

The token string looks like this:

```
Hello %{receiver.firstname} %{receiver.lastname}
```

And it outputs

```
Hello Anna Palmer
```

This is the method that does it:

```
def parse_body(resource, receiver, payload)
    if payload['body']
      payload['body'] % {
        "sender.firstname".to_sym => resource.owner.firstname,
        "sender.lastname".to_sym => resource.owner.lastname,
        "sender.email".to_sym => resource.owner.email,
        "receiver.fullname".to_sym => receiver.fullname,
        "receiver.firstname".to_sym => receiver.firstname,
        "receiver.lastname".to_sym => receiver.lastname,
        "receiver.email".to_sym => receiver.email,
        "resource.id".to_sym => resource.id,
        "resource.title".to_sym => resource.try(:title)
      }
    end
  end
```

How can I format the token like this instead and make it work with my method?

```
Hello {{receiver.firstname}} {{receiver.lastname}}
```

Comment: https://www.rubyguides.com/2015/04/parsing-with-ruby/

Comment: That also looks just like a mustache/handlebars template and I would be suprised if someone hasn't written a Ruby parser for it.

Comment: No, there are no external templating systems. Just the code above.

Comment: Yes, but since the code above is basically handlebars you can use a handlebars parser to parse it unless you want to write a parser of your own.

Comment: Ah yes I understand but I am trying not to add more dependencies. Can't I just change the method above to take care of the new token format?